# How to setup a ethereum testnet node locally?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets

How to setup a ethereum testnet node locally?

I am new to ethereum please some one help sharing step by step links

Answer (score 2):

What operating system are you on? You need to run a node locally using either Geth or Parity. I prefer Geth. Either one will let you run a node on the Ethereum Ropsten testnet blockchain.

Once it's installed, with `apt-get install geth` on Ubuntu, you need to run `geth --testnet --syncmode="light" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"`. This will set up a one-off testnet that uses `syncmode="light"` to get a super quick copy of the blockchain. Shouldn't take longer than 15-20 mins. If you take out the `syncmode="light"` it'll take a couple hours to a day to sync, but will be re-usable.

Once it starts syncing, it'll say "imported new block headers" or "imported new state entries" for awhile. When the processed number catches up with the one at [ropsten.etherscan.io](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/), you're good to go and your node is caught up.

You're going to get a copy of the chaindata in your `~/.ethereum` folder if you're on Ubuntu, `~/AppData/Roaming/Ethereum` on Windows in the `chaindata` folder if you ran it without using light syncmode, and `lightchaindata` if you used light syncmode. You will need to delete this `lightchaindata` folder every time you want to run geth again on the fast sync mode.

The other parameters open up geth with web3 and via RPC, and let any domain connect to it. Once you've used Metamask or Ethereum Wallet or Mist to confirm you can connect to the testnet on localhost, you can tweak the options. Metamask is a chrome plugin that lets you access the blockchain. If you click the network in the top left of the plugin, you will be able to select LOCALHOST. If it connects, you're on your local geth testnet instance!

Comment: I am using windows 10. I need run node locally only to test my application

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows

Here is the Geth install path for your OS.

Comment: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ <-- here specifically. If you need it just for test, definitely use `syncmode="light"` because it will be done syncing in a much shorter time.

Comment: how to start node?

Comment: `geth --testnet --syncmode="light" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"` in the command line

Comment: I think when i kept ur above command in commandline it is               INFO [07-04|10:26:36] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=62.642ms  number=12096 hash=da8539…8a15ca ignored=0......   code is running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61527/discussion-between-swa-and-diabetesjones).

Comment: yes if the code is running then you just need to let it run! As long as the number keeps going up. Once it catches up to the number at ropsten.etherscan.io, you will have a fully synced node.

Comment: I got error and node running stopped and i again try to run same code i got error                                                                                                               Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Comment: You will need to close the terminal and re-open it, as you're trying to run another node at the same time at the same ip/port, which isn't allowed.